How to select a comment in tinymce?
I'm trying open the editor in the proper comment conversation when a conversation id is passed as parameter.
?conversation=mce-conversation_39114075621716702547563
I have tried something like this
init_instance_callback: (editor:any) => {
  if(this.conversationId){
    editor.execCommand("ToggleSidebar", false, "showcomments");
    editor.getDoc().querySelector('span.mce-annotation.tox-comment[data-mce-annotation-uid="'+ this.conversationId+'"]').click()
  }
  editor.on('CommentChange', (evt:any) => {
    this.commentChange(evt.getEventLog(this.now.toISOString()))
  });
},

Any advice ?
